# jQuery load() event handler for image

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, modal-dialog

Goodevening!

I am creating a modal, and want to wait until image-load before showing the modal, but jQuerys load() event handler has some crossbrowser issues. Is there an elegant way to void load(), like using some kind of ajax call?

When a link to an image is clicked, jQuery sends the img-tag via "content" to method.open

```
    method.open = function (content) {
    var img = $(content).attr("href");
    $content.empty().append("<img src='" + img + "' />");
    $(img).load(function(){
        //Move show up here
        //console.log("WUHU");
    });
    $modal.show();
```

Link to fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EUMnF/1/

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3877027/901048)

Comment: Try this [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/EUMnF/2/)